# jQuery Traversing - best method to use?

Tags: jquery, traversal, jquery-traversing

I've been aiming to do something simple..but not sure of the best approach.
I've ready through jQuery documentation but as this place offers sound advice - I'll punt the question here.

It's basically traversing.

Say I have this minimal code as a simple example (multiple elements on the same page):

```
<div class='collab'>
<div class='collab_text'>text</div><!--close collab_text-->
</div><!--close_collab-->

<div class='collab'>
<div class='collab_text'>text</div><!--close collab_text-->
</div><!--close_collab-->
```

In jQuery I simply want to fade `collab_text` on hover.
So I have:

```
$(".collab").hover(function(){
        $(".collab_text").fadeTo(700, 1.0);
    },function(){
        $(".collab_text").fadeTo(300,0.00001);                          
    });
```

This will obviously show all the `collab_text` for all elements when I hover over 1 item.
So my question is what is the correct method to get only the hovered `collab_text` to show.
`.next()` ?, `.find()` ?

I know my code should be:

```
$(".collab").hover(function(){
            $(this).XXX(".collab_text").fadeTo(700, 1.0);
        },function(){
            $(this).XXX(".collab_text").fadeTo(300,0.00001);                            
        });
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `find`, or `$()` with context

```
$(this).find(".collab_text").fadeTo(700, 1.0);
```

or

```
$('.collab_text', this).fadeTo(700, 1.0);
```

They are both equal:

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that `$` with the context argument will eventually just end up doing a `find` under the covers. But it's a style some folks prefer.

Comment: @Ropstah No it was in the original answer, did you see "edited by" in the answer? :s

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use `children('.collab_text')`:

```
$(".collab").hover(function(){
    $(this).children(".collab_text").fadeTo(700, 1.0);
},function(){
    $(this).children(".collab_text").fadeTo(300,0.00001);                          
});​
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/edjQ7/